# PHP MySQL join two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, songs and history. The songs table looks like:

```
ID | title      | artist      | duration
1  | some title | some artist | 83592
```

The history table looks like:

```
ID | title      |   artist    | duration | date_played
5  | some title | some artist | 83592    | 2012-08-08 11:22:00
```

How would I echo the ID from the songs table if the title and the artist from the most recent entry in the history table matches?

I tried `SELECT * FROM history JOIN songs ON title=songs.title AND artist=songs.artist ORDER BY date_played DESC LIMIT 0, 1` but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT s.ID
FROM songs s
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM history h ORDER BY date_played DESC LIMIT 1) lastHistory
ON lastHistory.title = s.title AND lastHistory.artist = s.artist
```

([Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54f95/3))

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM history A INNER JOIN songs B 
ON A.title=B.title AND A.artist=B.artist 
ORDER BY A.date_played DESC
```

My suggestion is in history table you can use song id of songs table instead of artist and title.

Table: Songs

```
ID | title      | artist      | duration
1  | some title | some artist | 83592
```

Table: History

```
ID | songid  | date_played
5  | 1       | 2012-08-08 11:22:00
```

So that you can bring some optimization in your schema.

Then you can try this query.

```
SELECT * FROM history A INNER JOIN songs B 
ON A.songid=B.ID ORDER BY A.date_played DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT songs.* 
FROM songs, (SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY DESC date_played LIMIT 1) hist_view
WHERE songs.title = hist_view.title 
    AND songs.artist = hist_view.artist
```

The above query creates and inline view of the most recently played song called hist_view (using LIMIT and ORDER BY DESC). It then joins with songs table to find the matching song on the basis of artist and title.

I would suggest you add something like song_id in the history table as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT   songs.id
FROM     songs,
         history
WHERE    songs.title = history.title
AND      songs.artist = history.artist
ORDER BY history.date_played DESC
```

or

```
SELECT     songs.id
FROM       songs
INNER JOIN history ON  history.title = songs.title
                   AND history.artist = songs.artist
ORDER BY   history.date_played DESC
```

but it would better if you organised your tables as suggested by Vinay.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
select songs1.id,history1.title,history1.artist 
from songs as songs1,history as history1
order by date_diplayed desc
```

i thing this query solve your problem

Comment: No, this would just do a complete Cartesian product of the two tables